# Не могу взять значение по итератору

Tags: c++, указатели, stl, итераторы

Как взять .second значение пары, на которую указывает .begin() от set, который находится в vector?

То есть моя конструкция выглядит как-то так:

```
vector<set<pair<int, string>, comp>> v(30);
```

Для простого `set<pair<int, int>>` это выглядело бы так: `(*s.begin()).second`, но наличие массива всё портит. Не получается никак сделать то, что надо...

Comment: У вас есть итератор, указывающий на нужный элемент множества, или нужный элемент вектора (множество)?

Comment: @Harry У меня есть только индекс для вектора. И мне нужно найти первый элемент пары, которая находится на .begin() в set в векторе. Сам set автоматически сортится через компаратор.

Comment: Тогда как в моем ответе - `v[i].begin()->second`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы как-то странно задали вопрос. **Где** в векторе находится нужный `set`?

Если это `i`-й элемент вектора, то этот `set` - `v[i]`. Если на него указывает какой-то итератор - скажем, `begin()` - то это `v.begin()`. А дальше можно считать, что это и есть ваш `s` из вопроса:

```
v[i].begin()->second
v.begin()->begin()->second
```

Или вот как выглядит перечисление всех `second`, имеющихся в векторе:

```
for(auto vi: v) for(auto si: vi) cout << si.second << endl;
```

Comment: И правда. Даже подумать не мог про то, что в vector set тоже может быть на .begin(). У меня идёт взятие по индексу. Не мог разобраться, где же какой оператор ставить... Спасибо.

Comment: Остался только один грустный момент: при таком взятии second я не могу его изменить. Пишет, что second - read-only object. Как поступать?

Comment: Так ведь во множестве по определению лежат неизменяемые объекты! Формально же вы не имеете права их менять - может нарушиться упорядоченность... Формально же лучше старый элемент удалить, а новый добавить. Можно попробовать через `const_cast`, но лично я считаю это занятие крайене нездоровым...

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз. Буду знать. Решил через удаление в повторную вставку элемента. set - единственное, что подходило для решения задачи.

Answer (score 1):

```
v.begin()->begin()->second;
```